# How to match on type OR method annotation only once

Tags: aop, guice, interceptor

I want to have a Guice interceptor that intercepts calls either to a class that is annotated, or a method that is annotated. I'd like to be able to combine both, ie. override the class annotation with a method annotation with different properties.

I have this working like this:

```
// Intercept all METHODS annotated with @MyAnnotation
bindInterceptor(
    Matchers.any(),
    Matchers.annotatedWith(company.MyAnnotation),
    new TracingInterceptor());

// Intercept all methods in CLASSES annotated with @MyAnnotation
bindInterceptor(
    Matchers.annotatedWith(company.MyAnnotation),
    Matchers.any(),
    new TracingInterceptor());
```

However when I annotate a class like this:

```
@MyAnnotation    
class MyClass {
    @MyAnnotation
    public void myMethod() {}
}
```

The interceptor gets called twice, which is bad!

Is there any way to avoid triggering the interceptor twice, but having the same behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by making your binders mutually exclusive, like this:

```
// Intercept all METHODS annotated with @MyAnnotation in classes not annotated with @MyAnnotation
bindInterceptor(
    Matchers.not(Matchers.annotatedWith(company.MyAnnotation)),
    Matchers.annotatedWith(company.MyAnnotation),
    new TracingInterceptor());

// Intercept all methods not annotated with @MyAnnotation in CLASSES annotated with @MyAnnotation
bindInterceptor(
    Matchers.annotatedWith(company.MyAnnotation),
    Matchers.not(Matchers.annotatedWith(company.MyAnnotation)),
    new TracingInterceptor());

// Intercept all METHODS not annotated with @MyAnnotation in CLASSES annotated with @MyAnnotation
bindInterceptor(
    Matchers.annotatedWith(company.MyAnnotation),
    Matchers.annotatedWith(company.MyAnnotation),
    new TracingInterceptor());
```